# does a inout port work as both in and out in same appplication

Tags: vhdl, microcontroller, avr, digital

I am trying to write a vhdl code including inout port and have this doubt that wheather a inout port act as both input and output in same program.Like i know reason to use inout pin is so that it works both ways,but my doubt is if you consider practical example like in microcontroller i see the pin act as input for one program or application and as output in another.Can the pin work ask both in and out in same program ?is that possible?(like in 1 clock cycle its in and in other another its out)
practically it seems like it cant happen.But can someone help with an answer

Comment: I recommend you design it mostly as separate inputs and outputs and either at the I/O pad or somewhere near the edge you combine the in, out, output enable, etc together.  And whether it can be at the same time is determined by that I/O pad or similar.  This way you can be flexible and the same code support both situations.

Comment: they cant truly be at the same time as the output will in some way interfere when doing something where you are using it as an input.  and if it is that weak then its not much of an output.  but if as answered someone implemented one, it only takes one case to say yes it has happened.

Comment: VHDL doesn't have pins and ports can be associated with nets in a design hierarchy. VHDL also provides a behavioral design description which can be *simulated* or with a synthesis eligible subset generate hardware. That subset includes the use of top level ports of mode inout that can model bidirectional pins. Note the existing answer and preceding comments make different assumptions. Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 3):

In your toplevel entity, the following code would allow you to both drive and sample a (bidirectional) port named `bidir_port`:

```vhdl
...

    bidir_port : inout std_logic;

...

signal bidir_port_output_level : std_logic;
signal bidir_port_output_enable : std_logic;
signal bidir_port_input_level : std_logic;

...

    -- output buffer with enable
    bidir_port <= bidir_port_output_level when bidir_port_output_enable = '1' else 'Z';
    -- input buffer
    bidir_port_input_level <= bidir_port;
```

**Output**: In order to drive the pin, `bidir_port_output_enable` has to be `'1'` at which point the output driver will turn on and drive the pin with the value of `bidir_port_output_level` (`'0'` or `'1'` in physical digital systems).  If `bidir_port_output_enable` is `'0'`, the driver is disabled (turned off) at which point the value of `bidir_port_output_level` is irrelevant.

**Input**: You can always sense the pin (even when you're driving it) as shown with the assignment to signal `bidir_port_input_level`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged your question with "avr", the answer in "Not at the same time."

You already think:

> like in 1 clock cycle its in and in other another its out

If the program in the AVR changes the direction of the pin while running, it is possible that one time the pin is an output while another time it is an input.

---

*For some completeness:*

In example the 8051 family of microcontrollers actually use their pins in both directions at the same time, from a physical view. The pins don't have a direction control. Instead their "high" level is kind of weak like a pull-up resistor. You can drive it "low" if you want. To accelerate the rising edge, on a change from low to high the microcontroller activates a not-so-weak transistor for 2 clock cycles.

Comment: On AVR, reading and writing memory (such as e.g. the ports) takes 2 clock cycles. Writing to the register which changes the port direction will take 2 clock cycles as well. So there will be at least 4 AVR clock cycles between reading from and writing to a pin.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, kind of. There are a few things to keep in mind though:
- when writing synthesizable code it is best to use it at the top-level only
- you need to infer or instantiate a bidirectional buffer (it handles the switching from input to output) 
- why do you need a bidirectional port? If just to be able to read an output value you should use a different approach
The microcontroller is a good high level menal model. But remember that the microcontroller is generic purpose hardware, with software being the application specific thing and there the ports are usually either in- or output*.
In an FPGA this is similar, but here the configuration is the application specific thing and the same principal applies.

The exeption here are protocols like I2C or MIIM which need bidirectional ports. In those instances it is the only way to go.
I am sure there are other cases where a bidirectional pin is a good/only option, but i cannot think of one right now.

*unless used for protocols, but see later in the text.